# Cannot obtain image of photo-sphere when photographer is not Google

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am using the Google Street View Image API ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/ ) to get a 640x640 bitmap of the photo-sphere currently displayed in my app. I am able to obtain this bitmap when Google has the copyright on the photo-sphere, but not when the photo-sphere was contributed by an individual. Am I doing something wrong or does the Google Street View Image API not return a bitmap in such case?

What I'm getting, when the author is an individual, is a white bitmap that says on it "Sorry, we have no imagery here".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue reported in the Google Maps API public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35831151

The issue was acknowledged by Google, however they didn't expose any ETA regarding when it might be fixed.

I can suggest staring the issue to express your interest and receive further updates from Google.

Comment: Thanks xomena. It isn't clear to me that the issue you refer to is the same as the one I raised. I'm saying that if the pano is not photographed by Google, no 'thumbnail' is returned. What makes you say the above is the same issue?

Comment: Does your pano Id look like one on the issue? Please note that sometimes you can have pano ID like "306pVZYuMt4LgK_zcu1wYw", this will work with Street View API, but sometimes the pano ID is like "F:-6ZQIVG78pvc/V9fg4HKXsnI/AAAAAAAAJ6o/HLf6jeYy4ekCRbWRD3BvPqTmGPj3OdqiwCJkC". The latter doesn't work in Street View API and I believe when somebody uploads images the pano IDs are these long ones.